# What is the best options for exporting Adobe AIR application?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air

I code Adobe AIR games with Flash Builder IDE. When exporting release version, the Android one offers two options: one with embedded active runtime and other with shared AIR.
Which is the best option should we choose? In case we select shared AIR, is any risk for our games? I mean, is this true that all Android device always have AIR now? (For us a smaller APK is always better, right? :D) 
Normally which option do you choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that all Android devices have AIR installed.  Likely it's far from it (though unfortunately I have no empirical data to give you - other than Adobe's [blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/) which in Spring of 2014 claimed **50 million+** installs)

So while you will hit a very sizable % of potential users (using shared AIR runtime), there is no guarantee that the end user will have the correct (or any) version of AIR installed on their Android device.

So if you want to target the broadest audience possible (at the expense of filesize), you would want to export with the run time embedded.

Of course, some users will be put off by your app if it's too big (especially the gamer crowd) so you have to balance that with having to inconvenience some users with downloading AIR first.

**Only you can decide what is best** and you should consider the following:

1. Who is my target audience? (gamers are more likely to have AIR already installed), casual users are way less likely to bother with AIR or know anything about it or updating it
2. How big is my app without the runtime?  If you're app is 200mb by itself, then adding the runtime doesn't really make much difference.  But if your app is only 2mb, then you're getting a 4-5x bloat.

Comment: That AIR runtime is smaller than you actually think (you say 20M, that's not true)

Comment: Did I say anywhere that the AIR runtime is 20mb?  At any rate it is for desktop which was the last thing I was working with,  I believe for android it's around 9mb - but that doesn't change anything about my answer. (or the question) - nor does it invalidate my answer.

Comment: @BotMaster - If you can supply a valid reason for a down-vote, lets hear it?

Comment: Yes you said 'if your app is 2M you'll get 10x bloat' which by my count is 20M. Yes that does invalidate your answer because the file size is one of the main concern in the question so you have to get it right. The air runtime is less than 10M which leaves about 40M of file size available when publishing to google play. In most modren game less than 10M is largely acceptable even for mobile. I voted down because 20M was more than double the actual runtime size which makes your answer false.

Comment: @BotMaster - The reference has been corrected (and was before my last comment)

Answer (score 2):

You do want embedded since this is a guaranty that your game will work correctly. If you choose shared then your app won't install on system with an older AIR runtime version and user might no know how to update it so they won't be able to try your app. Embed and you avoid all these potential problems.